# How to Perform addition of a group of data to another in the Same table and Column?

Tags: sql

[image: Desired Result]

I would like to add all products from Location2 to Location1 and deleting all Location2 Records(optional).
How do I do it without creating another table?

Current SQL Statement:

```
Update Table1
    set Quantity = (Convert(INT,Quantity) +
                    Convert(INT, (Select Quantity from Table1 where Location = 'Loc2')) )
    where Location = 'Loc1';
```

But this works only if there is 1 product. How do I modify the code to allow all my products to be updated?
Thank you.

P.S. Below is the screenshot of the desired before and after result, incase my attached screenshot cannot be shown.

[image: http://prntscr.com/h6i8g4]

Comment: `convert(int, . . .)` is not MySQL.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, Gordon's answer would be:

```
UPDATE t1
SET    t1.Quantity = (t1.Quantity + t2.Quantity)
FROM   Table1 t1
JOIN   Table1 t2
ON     t1.ProductId = t2.ProductId
WHERE  t1.Location = 'Loc1' and t2.Location = 'Loc2'
```

Comment: Thank you. Code is working as expected. Appreciate it!

Comment: That is not "SQL"  - the SQL standard does not define a `FROM` clause for the `UPDATE` statement. Did you mean "Microsoft SQL Server"?

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWER IS FOR MYSQL.  On closer inspection, the OP is not using MySQL.

You can use `join` in an `update`:

```
Update Table1 t1 join
       Table1 tt1
       on tt1.productId = t1.productId
    set t1.Quantity = (t1.Quantity + tt1.Quantity)
    where t1.Location = 'Loc1' and tt1.Location = 'Loc2';
```

I don't know why you would convert `quantity` to an integer.  It should already be stored as a number.

After checking the results, you can `delete` the "Loc2" rows:

```
delete t from table1 t
     where t.Location = 'Loc2';
```

I don't think you can do the `update`/`delete` in one statement in MySQL.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes you are right. Apart from that, I have tried your code and there are a few syntax error. I kinda new to SQL, may I know if there are anything that I would need to change ?

Comment: 1)"t1                     ": Incorrect Syntax, Expecting Set
2)"join                  ": Incorrect Syntax near 'Join'
3)"on                   ": Incorrect Syntax near 'on'
4)"set t1.Quantity" : Incorrect Syntax near '.'
5)"= ( t1.Quantity " : Incorrect Syntax near 't1'. Expecting '(', or Select.

These are the reports from the query. May I know if I'm missing out on anything ?

Comment: @andrioduser . . . Your question is tagged mysql, but you are clearly not using MySQL.

Comment: Removed. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. Code is working as expected. Appreciate it.